# Maven Plugin Error: Tests Failed

Tags: maven-3, neo4j, maven-assembly-plugin, batch-insert

I'm trying to install a plugin using Maven (batch importer for neo4j). Using

```
mvn clean compile assembly:single
```

Gave me an error that the directory could not be created. I changed it to:

```
sudo mvn clean compile package assembly:single
```

and it seemed to work, until the build failed because of the following tests:

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 27.798s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Mar 29 16:17:14 EDT 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 22M/949M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test (default-test) on project batch-import: There are test failures.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Please refer to /u/omusayev/batch-import/batch-import/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Having never used Maven before, this is quite cryptic. Does anyone have an idea of what these might mean, and how I can fix the problem? If I can provide any more information, please ask.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You left off the actual failure tests (which are above the snippet you pasted), but I'm guessing it's some weirdness in a test that doesn't really matter--try this:

```
sudo mvn clean compile package assembly:single -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```